# Work with hidden select elemens in splinter (and selenium)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, splinter

I have a problem with splinter. I try to execute this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://passport.yandex.com/registration/mail')
browser.find_by_name("hint_question_id").click()
browser.select("hint_question_id","12")
```

But get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/dm/appdata/local/temp/tmppiwmlb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8791:5)
```

I try to use selenium:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://passport.yandex.com/registration/mail")

driver.find_element_by_name("hint_question_id").click()

# navigate to the page
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
print select.options
print [o.text for o in select.options] # these are string-s
select.select_by_index('2')
```

But get the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/dm/appdata/local/temp/tmpzjqnnp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8791:5)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. This site use pseudo select. For Splinter after:

```
browser.find_by_name("hint_question_id").click()
```

needs write

```
browser.find_by_css("li[role=\"presentation\"]")[1].click()
browser.find_by_id("hint_answer").fill(firstname)
```

Work good.